# Where is a sensible place to put kube_config.yaml files on MWAA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, mwaa

The [example code in the MWAA docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-eks-example.html#eksctl-create-dag) for connecting MWAA to EKS has the following:

```py
#use a kube_config stored in s3 dags folder for now
kube_config_path = '/usr/local/airflow/dags/kube_config.yaml'
```

This doesn't make me think that putting the `kube_config.yaml` file in the `dags/` directory is a sensible long-term solution.

But I can't find any mention in the docs about where *would* be a sensible place to store this file.

Can anyone link me to a reliable source on this? Or make a sensible suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

From `KubernetesPodOperator` Airflow documentation:

> Users can specify a kubeconfig file using the config_file parameter, otherwise the operator will default to ~/.kube/config.

In a local environment, the `kube_config.yaml` file can be stored in specific directory reserved for Kubernetes (e.g. `.kube`, `kubeconfig`). Reference: [KubernetesPodOperator (Airflow)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html).

In the MWAA environment, where DAG files are stored in S3, the `kube_config.yaml` file can be stored anywhere in the root DAG folder (including any subdirectory in the root DAG folder, e.g. `/dags/kube`). The location of the file is less important than explicitly excluding it from DAG parsing via the `.airflowignore` file. Reference: [.airflowignore (Airflow)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#airflowignore).

Example S3 directory layout:

```
s3://<bucket>/dags/dag_1.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/dag_2.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/kube/kube_config.yaml
s3://<bucket>/dags/operators/operator_1.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/operators/operator_2.py
s3://<bucket>/dags/.airflowignore
```

Example `.airflowignore` file:

```
kube/
operators/
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'm not sure you need to add the config file to `.airflowignore` though, because it will only attempt to parse Python files for DAG definitions.

Comment: Ack, thanks for clarifying @LondonRob. In any case, this is how I've deployed kube config files in MWAA.